# How to fix my app that crash instead of make a call?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that start a call when it receives a specific message. Everything is alright except the app crashes when it should start the call.

The problem is at the line where I use `startActivity()`. I don't know why it crash. Can someone help me?

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        //....
            String cod = "message";
            if(smsBody.compareTo(cod) == 0){
                CallClass obj = new CallClass();
                obj.call();
            }
        //....
```

```
private class CallClass extends AppCompatActivity {

       public void call() {
           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+107222222"));
           startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Also I tried the code below:

```
private class CallClass extends AppCompatActivity {
       public void call() {
           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+107222222"));
           try{
               startActivity(callIntent);
           }
           catch(SecurityException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
```

But it don't solve my problem. I checked and I gave all permissions that app needs to start a call. In debugging mode I receive this message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: romania.ovi.smsapp, PID: 9715
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver romania.ovi.smsapp.SmsBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference   
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3388)
....
    W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: What's the exception you are getting? And, what's the code for startActivity and where within that is it failing?

Comment: "I don't know why it require to give as arguments _the context, the intent and bundle_." – I'm guessing that you've extended `ActivityCompat` (or maybe `ContextCompat`) which has a `startActivity()` method that requires a `Context` for the first argument. However, that is not an `Activity` class. It's a helper class with a bunch of static methods. Looking at your method, though, it seems like you don't want to extend anything, if that's meant to be a simple helper method. You would just call `startActivity()` on the `Context` passed into your method.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mike . I made a new calss which extend `AppCompatActivity` and there `startActivity()` worked without asking `Bundle` and `Context` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use an Activity as just another class. As a rule of thumb, if your are calling an Activity constructor, you are doing something wrong. Either the class should not be an activity or you should not be calling the constructor.

In your use case, you would be better off writing the call code in the BroadcastReceiver itself.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ...
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+107222222"));
   context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Edit:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+107222222"));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: It still don't work. I receive this message on debug console: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver romania.ovi.smsapp.SmsBroadcastReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat Have edited the answer. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And your method should probably look like this:

```
public void call(String message, Context context) {
    if(message.compareTo("SpecificMessage")){

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+40773733585"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. I created a new class which extend `AppCompatActivity` so I can use `startActivity()` without problems. But the app still crashes.

Comment: Does it crash right after you call startActivity?  Try wrapping the startActivity(callIntent); with a try/catch block try{startActivity(callIntent);} catch(SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  Set a breakpoint on the e.printStackTrace(); line.  If it fails on Security, you will need to check if the user gave permission to use the phone feature before you try to use it.

Comment: I tried as you said. I gave all permission it needed for calling but the app still crash. I posted the debug log for my problem. If you can take a look I would be glad. Thanks.

Comment: Have you declared your CallClass Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file?  
The only other thing I worry about is that your onReceive() callback is probably not running in the UI thread, so, you might need to do the startActivity() call wrapped in a runOnUiThread() block.